# Providing ftp access (of selected files) to users from a hashed repository of unique files

Tags: mount, symlink, ftp, repository

We have a portal where each user has an account and a file repository that goes with it.

Whenever any user uploads a file using a form, the php app hashes the file contents first and checks to see if the file already exists in the system (even if uploaded by a different user).

If the file exists, no new file is stored, instead the system only saves a row with the details of the uploading user and links to the original file. This method eliminates file duplicates and saves space .

But we are encountering a problem now; every user also gets an ftp account, which can be utilized to download his repository files.

Since only unique files are stored, we need a way to show to every user all files from his repository.

Since this isn't a simple ftp folder it requires tinkering around.

We have seen symlinks and file mounts, both are not practicable because the former blocks access on permission grounds and latter requires thousands of files to be mounted individually at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the common files with a owner unknown to any of the users.
   (some `admin` user).
2. When `userA` is downloading a common file, change the ownership of the
   file from `admin` to `userA`. By this way, `userA` will assume he is the
   owner of the file.
3. After the file download is complete, revert back the permission of file to
   `admin` user.

Comment: thanks but this doesn't solve the problem. The unique files are located in one folder. If I were to provide direct ftp access to that folder then the ftp user will see all the files, not only the files he owns. If there was a way & I could just change file ownership when the ftp user logs in then this will be a problem for other users who own those files too when they would log in simultaneously.